# Node API - Cannot GET /url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I know there are several version of this but I can't seem to find a solution for mine.
My server doesn't seem to see all routes in my routes file. It only matches the first one.

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import dotenv from "dotenv";

import tweetRoutes from "./src/routes/tweetRoutes.js";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.use("/api/tweets", tweetRoutes);

// DB connection
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
mongoose.connection.on("connected", () =>
    console.log("DB Connection Established!")
);


// Server
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on: ${PORT}`))
```

**tweetRoutes.js**

```
import { Router } from 'express'
import {
    createTweet,
    fetchTweets,
    fetchTweet,
    updateTweet,
    deleteTweet,
} from "../controller/tweetController.js";

const router = Router();

router.get("/", fetchTweets);
router.get("/:id", fetchTweet);
router.post("/create-tweet", createTweet);
router.patch("/:id", updateTweet); // Not working
router.delete("/:id", deleteTweet); // Not working

export default router;
```

In this case, the only route accessible is the first one, **fetchTweets**. Even when I pass an ID param to get a single tweet using the *fetchTweet* route, it routes to the first route. The other routes return a **404**.

What could I be doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share us the url you used to test the fetchTweet route just to make sure there is no mistake there?

Comment: Yeah sure.   **127.0.0.1:3000/api/tweets?id=61b9af93e88ee4de51c28b95**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for providing the url you used to test the fetchTweet route.

You should use the following path instead to reach the desired route:

```
127.0.0.1:3000/api/tweets/61b9af93e88ee4de51c28b95
```

Reference:

- https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html